# PHP - How To Compare Two Columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem in solving this quiz program. I am currently stuck at inserting a row. I'll explain it in detail: Let's say I have two tables, named "Table 1" and "Table 2". Table 1 has all the questions and correct answers which were inputted by the teacher. Table 2 contains answers given by students. How do I "compare" data from the 2 tables then insert the "result" of the student's answers, whether they're "correct" or "wrong", to Table 2? The image below is the kind of table I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I've been at it for almost a day and I've come to the conclusion that I am stuck.
May you provide me some ideas, concepts, or even sample codes?

**tl;dr: Compare table1.correct_answer to table2.student_answer then provide data for table2.result**

Comment: What is the problem here ?

Comment: The problem has been resolved, thank you for your concern though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the two tables have id columns and the questions and answers are in the same order (with same id). You could do something like this:

First put all the corrects answers into an array.

```
$result1 = mysql_query("Select * From table1");
while ($correct_row = mysql_fetch_array($result1) ){
    $correct[ $correct_row[id] ] =  $correct_row[correct_answer];
}
```

Then compare them with the students answers and update the table of the result while going thru every answer of the student.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("Select * From table2");
while ($student_row = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ){
    if ($student_row[student_answer] == $correct[ $student_row[id] ]  ){
        mysql_query("UPDATE table2 SET result=correct WHERE id=$student_row[id]");
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE table2 SET result=wrong WHERE id=$student_row[id]");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me a general idea on solving the problem! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Table1 should have some kind of ID. Table2 needs a column with references Table1s ID as a foreign key.

Comment: Hi there,
thank you for answering. I forgot to mention that your suggestion was already implemented prior to my questioning. May you provide me a sample code to process data for table2.result?

Comment: You should first read the questions from table 1 ("Select * From Table1"). Then iterate the result and for every row read the rows from Table2 where the reference id is equal the id from the row ("Select * From Table 2 WHERE reference = row.id"). Another solution would be joints but i think this manual way is easier for you to implement and understand.